# PHP Code correction

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, formatting

i have this code snippet:

```
$num_thumbs = 3;
$thumb_p = "<li>\n<div class=\"row-wrapper\">\n";
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach ($thumbs_array as &$thumb_link) {
if ($i == $num_thumbs) {
  $i = 0;
  $thumb_p .= "<div class=\"some-class-2\">" . $thumb_link . "</div>";
  $thumb_p .= "</div>\n";
  if($j == 3)
  {
      $thumb_p .= "</li>\n<li>";
      $j = 0;
  }
  $thumb_p .= "<div class=\"row-wrapper\">\n";
  $j++;
} else {
  $thumb_p .= "\t\n<div class=\"some-class-1\">" . $thumb_link . "</div>";
  $i++;
}
}
$thumb_p .= "\n</div>\n</li>\n";
```

it should wrap `<div class=\"row-wrapper\">` between `<li></li>` after every three occurrences.

Problem is that i get one extra line at the bottom every time:

```
<li>
<div class="row-wrapper">
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: $thumb_p .= "\n</div>\n</li>\n"; If you remove the last \n ?

Comment: This is not a code correction it's a logic correction. Because faulty logic creates unwanted behaviour as opposed to errors.

Comment: Try to use the PHP alternate syntax `<?php foreach($items AS $item): ?> <li></li> <?php endforeach; ?>` it makes your code clearer and easier to follow.

Comment: Also remember that Stack Overflow is not a debugging platform or a collaborative programming platform. If you know how to use the code you've written, trace your steps backwards, put your conditions on a piece of paper and try writing it again, don't ask other people to do your work for you.

Comment: what do you mean by this ..`Problem is that i get one extra line at the bottom every time:` ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this line

```
$thumb_p .= "</li>\n<li>";
```

Does it not cause you trouble? I think it should be

```
 $thumb_p .= "<li>\n</li>";
```

Comment: I don't think so. The OP's version makes more sense.